# Can we change the URL route in between ingress and service?

Tags: angular, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a docker image which hosts it's server on `/` (home)
now, in ingress I already have a service(homepage) which belongs to `/`

What I want:

1. going to `/` should take me to the home page
2. going to `/custom` should take me to the docker service pointing to the image

but the problem is that since, the image is hosted on `/` it doesn't work on `/custom`.
Ingress forwards it to the service but service doesn't recogize /custom, so I get **NotFound**
and I don't have control over the image hosting path.

Is there any way around?
someway I could add `/custom` in ingress but remove it after the service is called or something else.

CODE:

```
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 20m
    # Below is to counter gateway timeout issue.
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: 3600s
spec:
  rules:
     - host: www.mysite.com  
          http:
            paths:
              - path: /custom
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: image-service
                    port:
                      number: 80 
              - path: / 
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: frontend-service
                    port:
                      number: 80
```

image-service will only work if the URL is `/`

EDIT: Tried rewrite with ingress
It works almost as I need it except for one issue,
I only see the favicon(so i know the service is working) but the page is not loaded(404 resource error on console)
of my **angular** app (hash location strategy)
It also doesn't work with react (same issue)
What am I missing?

Comment: (a) you failed to include the actual code so that someone could give you code advice (b) does that mean you're not aware of [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#examples)?

Comment: @mdaniel I have added the code, I am not aware of rewrite. I think that is probably what I need, it's not the best documentation though. What is $2? how to use that? Can I fool the image-service into thinking that the path is still /

Comment: The answer to "What is $2?" is right at the top of the page, called out in a note: "Captured groups are saved in numbered placeholders, chronologically, in the form $1, $2 ... $n. These placeholders can be used as parameters in the rewrite-target annotation."

Comment: @larsks yeah, I read it and updated the question.
I think I should close this one and ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, This can be done using nginx rewrite [example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#examples).
Adding:
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` to annotations

There are two things to note here:

1. `$1`,`$2` represents a capture group, basically it means that the content that matches the group will be rewritten.
   eg: `/custom(/|$)(.*)`
   `(/|$)` *covers* `custom/` or `custom` [GROUP1 `$1`]
   `(.*)` *means* everything after `custom/` or `custom` [GROUP2 `$2`]

Now, If I choose `$2`, then `/custom/xyz` will become `/xyz` **FOR THE SERVICE** as only `/xyz` will belong to group two

[Play with regex](https://regexr.com/)

2. For some reason, once I added rewrite, basic `/` path stopped working
   which I modified to `/(.*)` for `$1` rewrite

*If you are using `$2`, `/()(.*)` should work.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Virtualserver in Nginx controller see this document:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).